# ActiveMQ+Spring bind port 61617

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

I've been trying to make ActiveMQ bind port 61617 instead of 61616. I'm using Spring in my application and have the following config:

```
@Configuration
```

public class MessagingConfiguration {

```
private static final String DEFAULT_BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:61617";

private static final String ORDER_QUEUE = "order-queue";

@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    template.setDefaultDestinationName(ORDER_QUEUE);
    return template;
}
```

}

Using netstat -an|find "61616" i see that ActiveMQ still binds 61616 and not 61617 (netstat -an|find "61617"). Any ideas as to how to make ActiveMQ use 61617?

Answer (score 3):

this config is to tell to your client to connect to broker @ port **61617** using tcp connector and not changing the broker default port.

AMQ default embedded config is only creating a VM connector, not tcp for this you need to define the broker bean to override default config and add tcp connector... :

```
@Bean
public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
    final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61617");
    broker.addConnector("vm://localhost");
    return broker;
}
```

why not using VM connector since the broker is embedded ?

**UPDATE:**

if you want to externalize your url or config you can use properties (amqUrl need to be in a properties file used and loaded by the context) :

```
@Value("${amqUrl}")
String amqUrl;

@Bean
public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
    final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.addConnector(amqUrl);
    broker.addConnector("vm://localhost");
    return broker;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to make the AMQ config bind to another port? I'm asking this because while the port 61616 is free in my development environment and everything works fine but it's bound in the deployment environment.

Comment: i do not understood, is it not what is done by **broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61617");** ? see my updated answer to externalize your url